# Hide string array list above dropdown laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

Here is the code for a dropdown in a laravel view.

```
{{ Form::select(manager_id,$managers,$selected,array('class'=>'dropdown')) }}
```

Why am I seeing the "stringArray ( [4] => Manager2 [6] => Man )" line above?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten single quote around manager_id in form syntax:-

```
{{ Form::select('manager_id',$managers,$selected,array('class'=>'dropdown')) }}
```

Refer this [laravel cheatsheet](http://cheats.jesse-obrien.ca/).

Hope it will help you :-)